# SSL Certificate verification fail exception on certain device in flutter

Tags: flutter, http-proxy, flutter-http

When I am creating the flutter app and debugging it then it shows the following error certificate_verify_failed: certificate has expired(handshake.cc:359))
But this error is in the old version of Android not in Android 10 and above. I have resolved this issue with httpClient neglecting exception. But I want to know how should I proceed further to avoid this issue. Without compromising my security. when i check on digicert website i found following issue
The Certificate is not issued by DigiCert, GeoTrust, Thawte, or RapidSSL
Now what to do.

Comment: Old versions of ssl have s bug where if intermediate certs expire,  they consider the server cert expired as well.   This is a mistake,  as certs signed with an intermediate on its last minute of validity are still validly signed.   It could well be that bug, and the only solution is library upgrade.   If that's not possible on your device,  welcome to the feel of planed obsolescence.

Comment: So I need to get new SSL or just ignore the error

Comment: Don't ignore SSL cert validity errors - if you can't update the device, you should consider it at end of life.